# Multiple Tables Authentication laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have Two tables .

```
Table One: users ::  localhost/login.php
Table Two: resellers :: localhost/resellers/login.php
```

My Route:

```
 // Route for login users.
 Route::get('/login.php', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
 Route::post('/login.php', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
```

and my function postLogin() :

```
  $this->validate($request, [
        'user' => 'required', 'password' => 'required', 
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('user', 'password');

    if ($this->auth->attempt( $credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        return '1';
    }


    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('user', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'user' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
```

The login page users working fine , I want create a new route and using it for resellers and check user & password in resellers table.

How to do it ?

I created two model with Users and Resellers.

I many searched in google and websites but donest find any good way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately It is not possible in laravel 5.0.
What you can do is install this package https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth
And you can do something like this to authenticate user from multiple tables.

**Login using users table**

```
Auth::user()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)
```

**Login using resellers table**

```
Auth::reseller()->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)
```

Hope this helps.